# Sh alias equivalent of PowerShell Set-Alias

Tags: powershell, sh, alias

What would be the equivalent of this PowerShell code in Sh:

```
Set-Alias -Name PS7 -Value "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe"
PS7 {
  $PSVersionTable
  1..5 | ForEach-Object -Parallel { Write-Host $_  } -ThrottleLimit 5
}
```

I tried the following:

```
alias ps="C:/Program Files/PowerShell/7/pwsh.exe"
ps {
  $PSVersionTable
  1..5 | ForEach-Object -Parallel { Write-Host $_  } -ThrottleLimit 5
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Is it even possible? I would like it to be inline, not in a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you are in `WSL`:

```
alias ps=\"$(wslpath -u 'D:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe')\"
alias ps
```

> ```
> alias ps='"/mnt/d/Program Files/PowerShell/7/pwsh.exe"'
> ```

```
ps -nopro -c '& {
  $PSVersionTable
  1..5 | ForEach-Object -Parallel { Write-Host $_  } -ThrottleLimit 5
}'
```

> ```
> Name                           Value
> ----                           -----
> PSVersion                      7.0.3
> PSEdition                      Core
> GitCommitId                    7.0.3
> OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19041
> Platform                       Win32NT
> PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
> PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
> SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
> WSManStackVersion              3.0
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> ```

FYI, I'm on the following (run from `cmd`): `ver & wsl --list`

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.508]
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Ubuntu-20.04 (Default)
Ubuntu-18.04
```

Comment: I'm not on WSL, but thanks to your suggestions I managed to make it to work: `                    alias ps='"C:/Program Files/PowerShell/7/pwsh.exe"'
                    ps -nopro -c '& {
                        $PSVersionTable
                        1..5 | ForEach-Object -Parallel { Write-Host $_  } -ThrottleLimit 5
                    } '`